# Issues while opening a UTF16 encoded .csv file in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, encoding, export-to-excel, utf-16

I am trying to open a `UTF8(Unicode)` encoded .csv file in excel, doing something like this:

```
m_excel.Workbooks.OpenText(newPath, Comma: true);
```

and that works fine. Can anyone tell me what to do if I had to open a `UTF16` encoded file similarly.
Currently using above function overloads are throwing me all sorts of exception

Thanks.

Comment: Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I won't be able to help you, but I'm sure providing these "all sorts of exceptions" along with conditions for them to be thrown (surely they are not thrown randomly) would help anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, i should have mentioned in the first place..# HRESULT Exception : 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)...This i am getting when using the OpenText() function overloads.I am not very much sure about the function also..this i get when i used m_excel.Workbooks.OpenText(newPath,OtherChar:UnicodeEncoding.Unicode, Comma: true); overload.